# What is the best way to update the model from a blur event?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My objective is to create an Angular directive called "myphone" that performs US phone number validation and formatting on an input field just by adding this attribute.  I would like the validation to occur as data is typed, but I would like the formatting to occur when the field has lost focus.  The formatted phone number is sent when the form is submitted.  I spent some time and came up with the solution shown below and I believe it works as desired.

I have a few questions though:

(1) Should I be checking modelValue or viewValue inside the validator?  In this situation they always appear to be identical so I guess it doesn't matter, but I suspect one is a "better" choice.

(2) What is the best way to update the model from a blur event?  I came up with `scope[ ctrl.$name ] = tel`, but I suspect that isn't a great way to do it. OK - that was not the way to do it.  Apparently I should be using `$parse`.

(3) My initial approach was to create a formatter.  It appears that formatters are only called when the field is initially populated and I couldn't figure how to invoke the formatter from the blur event.  Would this be a better approach?  If so, how can I invoke the formatter from the blur event?

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
<form name=form novalidate ng-app="app">
   <label>Phone</label>
   <input name=phone ng-model="phone" myphone>
   <span ng-show="form.phone.$dirty && form.phone.$invalid">Invalid phone.</span>
</form>
<script>
var app = angular.module( 'app', [ ] );
app.directive( 'myphone', [ '$parse', function( $parse )
{
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function( scope, elm, attrs, ctrl ) {
         ctrl.$validators.myphone = function( modelValue, viewValue ) {
            if ( !angular.isString( modelValue ) || !modelValue.length ) return true;
            /* Accept a 10 digit phone number.  Ignore leading "1" if present. */
            var pattern = new RegExp( /^1?[2-9][0-8]\d[2-9]\d{6}$/ );
            /* Ignore non-digits */
            return pattern.test( viewValue.replace( /[^0-9]/g, '' ) );
         };
         elm.bind( 'blur', function( ) {
            scope.$apply( function ( ) {
               var tel = $parse( attrs.ngModel )( scope );
               if ( angular.isString ( tel ) ) {
                  /* Remove non-digits */
                  tel = tel.replace( /[^0-9]/g, '' );
                  tel = tel.replace( /^(?:1?)([2-9][0-8]\d)([2-9]\d{2})(\d{4})$/, '($1) $2-$3' );
                  $parse( attrs.ngModel ).assign( scope, tel );
               }
            } )
         } );
      }
   };
} ] );
</script>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/N0pNucY1SyhEc9JHfcB4

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-model-options directive provided by angular. 
Read more at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: Thanks.  I gave it a try.  If I defer updates until the blur event, then validation is deferred also.